# Workflow Designer | The Operation has Timed out

Tags: workflow, 2011-sp1, visio-designer

When I try connecting the CM from Visio Workflow Designer by double clicking the any WF activity, the designer pops up a dialog to enter credentials and after submitting the credentials, I am getting the exception as below after a minute or so.

> The operation has timed out
>
> System.Web.Services()

[image]

I checked logs, it looked a timeout issue to me so I increased timeout values (to 03.00.00 ) for "CoreService_netTcpBinding" binding in "web.config" at path "{TridionInstallDirectory}\Web" and in "TcmServiceHost.exe.config" at path "{TridionInstallDirectory}\bin", but getting the same error as below:

> The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error
> processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the
> remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket
> timeout was '03:00:00'. The write operation failed, see inner
> exception. The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by
> an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded
> by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local
> socket timeout was '03:00:00'. An existing connection was forcibly
> closed by the remote host   Component:
> Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService Errorcode: 0 User: NT
> AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE  StackTrace Information Details:    at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.Write(Byte[] buffer,
> Int32 offset, Int32 size, Boolean immediate, TimeSpan timeout)    at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.Write(Byte[] buffer,
> Int32 offset, Int32 size, Boolean immediate, TimeSpan timeout)    at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedConnection.WriteNow(Byte[]
> buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, BufferManager
> bufferManager)    at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedConnection.Write(Byte[] buffer,
> Int32 offset, Int32 size, Boolean immediate, TimeSpan timeout)    at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionStream.Write(Byte[] buffer,
> Int32 offset, Int32 count)    at
> System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.StartWriting(Byte[] buffer, Int32
> offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
> System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.ProcessWrite(Byte[] buffer, Int32
> offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
> System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.ProcessWrite(Byte[] buffer, Int32
> offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
> System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
> Int32 count)    at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamConnection.Write(Byte[] buffer,
> Int32 offset, Int32 size, Boolean immediate, TimeSpan timeout)    at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamConnection.Write(Byte[] buffer,
> Int32 offset, Int32 size, Boolean immediate, TimeSpan timeout)    at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamConnection.Write(Byte[] buffer,
> Int32 offset, Int32 size, Boolean immediate, TimeSpan timeout,
> BufferManager bufferManager)    at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.FramingDuplexSessionChannel.OnSendCore(Message
> message, TimeSpan timeout)    at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportDuplexSessionChannel.OnSend(Message
> message, TimeSpan timeout)    at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.OutputChannel.Send(Message message,
> TimeSpan timeout)    at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransactionDuplexChannelGeneric`1.Send(Message
> message, TimeSpan timeout)    at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContextBase.Reply(Message message,
> TimeSpan timeout)    at
> System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.Reply(MessageRpc&
> rpc)

AND

> Thread was being aborted.
>
> Component: Tridion.ContentManager.Workflow.DesignerService Errorcode:
> 0 User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
>
> StackTrace Information Details:    at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
> message)    at
> System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
> msgData, Int32 type)    at
> Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.ISessionAwareCoreService.GetSystemWideList(SystemWideListFilterData
> filter)    at
> Tridion.ContentManager.Workflow.DesignerService.WFListener.GetSystemWideList[T,FT](ListBaseColumns
> baseColumns, FT other)    at
> Tridion.ContentManager.Workflow.DesignerService.WFListener.GetWorkflowData()

Am I missing increasing the timeout value somewhere or it's unrelated to increasing timeout?

**UPDATE**

While connecting, it looks like Tridion iterates through and performs several different `Tridion.ContentManager.Workflow.DesignerService.WFListener.GetSystemWideList()` methods. These methods in turn make a database call and read data back as a result of the call.
the final iteration of the GetSystemWideList() method makes the following database call:

```
TCM_WORKFLOW_GETLIST_PROCESS_DEFINITIONS
```

While the database call itself take less than 100ms to complete, it looks like the resulting data read takes a whopping 2+ minutes to complete in Sandbox.

I tried browsing Workflow Process Definitions in Tridion Browser. And it take around 2 mins to respond but present the results in the end without timing out.

Comment: It should not be needed to increase the timeout to 3 minutes; that's just symptom resolution.  Does it really take 3 minutes before you get the error?  It seems to timeout when retrieving some system-wide list from Core Service. Have you done DB maintenance?

Comment: No, it doesn't take 3 mins Rick. I will try it after doing the the DB maintenance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So to fix the issue we did the following:

1. Turned the **Tracing off** on CMS Server.
2. Our DB was of 2013 version and not in sync with Tridion Version 2013SP1.

I don't think it was because of the point 2, because it was working fine from long back with the same setup. So I guess, it was the Tracing. I also noticed, we had huge logs(in GBs) on CMS server and purged those later.

Answer (score 1):

*assuming*:

- you can connect to other environments (this reduces the likelihood of it being Visio or Workflow Plugin related)
- you have all logs on DEBUG and see nothing other than what you've posted (including the windows event logs)
- your user still has the correct permissions and you can perform the usual functions in Tridion (such as triggering a GetList for a Publication list etc.)
- everything looks good as far as IIS, Services, COM component
- you can see that there was no Windows/JAVA/other updates since Visio / workflow last worked

  .
- I think it's unnecessary but it's a step that Support would ask you to take - I'd uninstall and reinstall the plugin (and confirm all is well connecting to another environment still before moving on)

Then, I'd:

- run sp_updatestats (this should be running on a schedule anyway - even on a sandbox machine - I'd ask DevOps to rectify this if it isn't the case)
- I'd be reluctant to start cleaning up in the hope if fixes a *seemingly unrelated* issue (but nice to flag purge scripts and other DB Maintenance as general good practice later)
- at this point, I'd be starting a Support Ticket
- when/if sp_updatestats doesn't work I would work with DevOps and put a TRACE on the SQL DB - watch what SQL queries are executed (if any - given it seems some web service isn't responding - it may still be making valid requests)
- if SQL TRACE shows nothing it may help to dig deeper into what's going on behind the scenes (using a tool such as DynaTrace) with - catching the error at that deep level may surface some error report you're not otherwise seeing

Comment: This isn't intended specifically as an answer but it's a little long for just a comment :)